# Create a non filled arc in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

(simplified) : I've have created this simple code to create an `arc`

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/epumeg/1/edit)

The result is :

[image]

but I *don't* want it to be full filled with red.

I need something like this : (edited with photoshop)

[image]

(simple words : , if it was a div , then  `style="border:solid 1px red;background-color:white"`)

question :

How can I enhance my code to do that by not filling the whole shape ? Is there any property which allows me to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround for this is to draw 2 arcs: One red with a `lineWidth` of 10 and then another one on top in white and a `lineWidth` of 6 or 8.

Note: Odd numbers might yield better results (11 and 9/7):

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var radius = 55;

  var y = canvas.height / 2;

  context.beginPath();

  var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 1.9 * Math.PI;
  var delta = 0.005 * Math.PI;
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle  , false);
  context.lineWidth = 11;

  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle+delta, endAngle-delta, false);
  context.lineWidth = 9;

  context.strokeStyle = 'white';
  context.stroke();
```

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/epumeg/9/edit)

Comment: Thanks Aaron...can you please elaborate on _Odd numbers might yield better results (11 and 9/7):_ ?

Comment: Odd line widths sometimes give better results when drawing over them because they don't cause rounding errors - which seems odd. Think of a line with width 6 that you draw from 5,0 to 5,10. Which pixels will be set? 5-6/2=5-3=2 to 5+3=8. But that means the line isn't centered since there are three black pixels to the left of the drawing position and only two on the right: `***x**` where "x" is the start coordinate. `***x***` (= width 7) has a the same amount of pixels on both sides. So when you start rotating this line, it won't suddenly to "jump".